# Difference in Current Transformer Ratings?

Tags: ac, current-measurement, voltage-measurement

I am looking at two current transformers, the SCT-013-000 and SCT-013-000V. ([Datasheet for both](https://www.mcielectronics.cl/website_MCI/static/documents/Datasheet_SCT013.pdf))

The SCT-0130-000 states that it has an output of 0-50mA, and for the V variant, it has an output of 0-1V AC. I am assuming that on the non-V, output voltage is constant, and output current changes, and on the V variant, current is fixed, and voltage stays the same. Is this accurate? and if so, how do I know what voltage and current the non-V and V variants are fixed at respectively?

Also, As far as I can tell, both SCTs are identical, other than the TVS (transient voltage suppressor) used in the schematic:[image: CTS]

What are these types of TVS's called, and do they change whether the CT varies the voltage and current? From what I've read, a TVS is only used as protection to prevent too much voltage on the output:

> The purpose of the transient voltage suppressor is to limit the voltage that may appear on the plug and across the windings to a safe value should the transformer be unplugged from the burden in the transmitter/instrument, whilst the primary is energised.

Taken from [Here](https://learn.openenergymonitor.org/electricity-monitoring/ct-sensors/yhdc-sct-013-000-ct-sensor-report#the-yhdc-current-transformer).

If changing the type of TVS is what changes the output type, what would happen if both TVS were included in series or parralel? Would voltage and current be fixed? What if no TVS was included? (I would like to try to have one sct with two isolated outputs, one where voltage varies, and one where current varries.)

Finally, If my initial assumption was wrong, about voltage being fixed on the non-V variant, and current fixed on the V variant, How is it possible that the output would be 50mA, but 0V AC or vice-versa?

My end goal is to power a low power microcontroller off the output of an SCT. Obviously if the SCT was clamped on a wire with low / no amps, then the microcontroller would turn off, but my hope is that the scenario will be that on an 100A SCT, if the source is 20+ A, it will power up the microcontroller.

Comment: From datasheet is clear that voltage output has built-in resistor.

Comment: Right, But how/ why does this work, and why is a protective diode only included in one, and why are they both labeled TVS?

Comment: Ask the manufacturer why they called resistor as TVS. Current transformer may be damaged by high voltage then the load is high resistance. TVS diode restrain the output voltage, simple resistor too. It is possible mistake in drawing.

Comment: It is confusing but what I think is the TVS is used to limit the voltage, if it is not there and it is open circuited you can get several hundred volts. The load (burden) keeps the voltage to a safe level, it acts like a pseudo reducing current mirror.

Comment: The output of the CT is only tied to the input by magnetic field, and you can't creat power, and E=I*R. Knowing this, why would several hundred volts be dangerous if its at mAs? max output would be 50mA at 1v. If that ran away to 100v, it would be at less than 0.5mA, which is almost nothing. If that was concerning, wouldnt a capacitor to ground be a better way to absorb that? not trying to argue, just trying to understand, thanks

Comment: Theoretically if output resistance is infinite, open circuit, voltage can be infinite too. But practically the wires insulation will be broken down and shortage will happen.

Comment: CT should not be used without low resistance load. It is "foolproof" design.